# Hex to decimal conversion from a bufferreader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am having a lot of trouble getting my code to read a certain file, which has 4 hex codes, using buffer reader and converting it to decimal. I was able to get the bufferreader to read the text file and output it to the compiler but i need the program to store the 4 values and have my method convert hex to decimal. This is what i have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HexToDecimal {

public static int hexToDecimal(String hexInput) throws IOException {
int decimal = 0;
int len = hexInput.length();

FileReader in = new FileReader("results.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     out.printf(line + "\n");
}
in.close();


for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    char c = hexInput.charAt(i);
    int cValue;

    switch (c) {
    case '1':
        cValue = 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        cValue = 2;
        break;
    case '3':
        cValue = 3;
        break;
    case '4':
        cValue = 4;
        break;
    case '5':
        cValue = 5;
        break;
    case '6':
        cValue = 6;
        break;
    case '7':
        cValue = 7;
        break;
    case '8':
        cValue = 8;
        break;
    case '9':
        cValue = 9;
        break;
    case 'A':
        cValue = 10;
        break;
    case 'B':
        cValue = 11;
        break;
    case 'C':
        cValue = 12;
        break;
    case 'D':
        cValue = 13;
        break;
    case 'E':
        cValue = 14;
        break;
    case 'F':
        cValue = 15;
        break;
    default: // unexpected character
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-hex character " + c
            + " found at position " + i);
    }
    decimal = 16 * decimal + cValue;
}
return decimal;

}

 public static void main(String[] args) { 

} 

}
```

Also i can't use parseInt that's why i'm using case breaks. Which is also giving me trouble when it comes to converting hex to decimal. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what giving you trouble?

Comment: Please also add an example of a possible input string. And a stacktrace in case of exceptions. Is your `main`really empty??

Comment: I would use hex A2 which should give me 162 but i keep getting 115 when I write System.out.println ('A' + '2'); just so that i can test the case break calculations. What is giving me trouble is trying to get the program to convert the hex in the text file to decimal. I don't know how to store the values of the text file and have my case brake convert it to decimal.

Comment: `'A' + '2'` is character not string instead use `"A"+"2"`.

Comment: the output i get for that is literally A2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your code in that way and it will work:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class HexToDecimal {

    public static BigInteger hexToDecimal(String hexInput) throws IOException {
        BigInteger decimal = BigInteger.ZERO;
        int len = hexInput.length();

        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = hexInput.charAt(len - i - 1);
            BigInteger cValue;

            switch (c) {
            case '1':
                cValue = BigInteger.ONE;
                break;
            case '2':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(2l);
                break;
            case '3':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(3l);
                break;
            case '4':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(4l);
                break;
            case '5':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(5l);
                break;
            case '6':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(6l);
                break;
            case '7':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(7l);
                break;
            case '8':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(8l);
                break;
            case '9':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(9l);
                break;
            case 'A':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(10l);
                break;
            case 'B':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(11l);
                break;
            case 'C':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(12l);
                break;
            case 'D':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(13l);
                break;
            case 'E':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(14l);
                break;
            case 'F':
                cValue = BigInteger.valueOf(15l);
                break;
            default: // unexpected character
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non-hex character " + c
                        + " found at position " + i);
            }
            decimal = decimal.add(cValue
                    .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(16).pow(i)));
        }
        return decimal;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader in = new FileReader("results.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] hexNums = line.split(" ");
            for (String hex : hexNums)
                out.printf(hexToDecimal(hex) + "\n");
        }
        in.close();

    }

}
```

If you have to big numbers then you get a wrong answer with int as type so you have to use BigInteger and then the code looks like above with reading from file and printing to the output stream.
I hope it helps.

Comment: "i can't use parseInt". check OP statement

Comment: Sorry haven't seen that, but now it should be alright.

Comment: This actually helped a lot. The system.out.println(hexToDecimal("C1")); worked with the original code without having to change the for loop or the equation after the case breaks. Now all i need help with is getting the information from the "results.txt" file, which also has hex, to output as decimal.

Comment: How is the hex represented in the file? In one line or with words? And how big is the hex string?

Comment: ABCDEFABC
1A00D0000
7A0EDF301
3CDAEFFAD

Comment: Is the hex separated by space?

Comment: its four different hex numbers and i need to be able to read all of them from the file and convert them to decimal, hence the  bufferreader. I can read it from the bufferreader but i can't seem to convert it using the case break method

Comment: when i compile it all it gives me is the four hex numbers within the file

Comment: This is great i was using my original code and the values were way too big so i ended up with the wrong result. The BigInterger fixed it all. My only question is what do the values inside the case breaks where you put BigInteger.valueOf(31) mean? Specifically 21, 31, 41 etc.

Comment: That is not 31 it is 3l the second character is a small 'L' and it stands for a long value.

Answer (score 0):

As Leonid Glanz said just convert the hex String to decimal with Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16). To store more than one value just use a ArrayList.

Edit: Sry didn't read your Op correctly

Here is a bit of code you can use:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HexToDecimal {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> hexToDecimal() throws IOException {
        FileReader in = new FileReader("results.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        String ram = "";
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             lines.add(line); 
        }
        for(String y : lines){
            ram = "";
            for(char x : y.toCharArray()){
                ram += convert(x);
            }
            output.add(Integer.parseInt(ram));
        }

        in.close();
        return output;
    }

    public static int convert(char x){
        if(x == '1'){
            return 1;
        }else if(x == '2'){
            return 2;
        }else if(x == '3'){
            return 3;
        }else if(x == '4'){
            return 4;
        }else if(x == '5'){
            return 5;
        }else if(x == '6'){
            return 6;
        }else if(x == '7'){
            return 7;
        }else if(x == '8'){
            return 8;
        }else if(x == '9'){
            return 9;
        }else if(x == 'A'){
            return 10;
        }else if(x == 'B'){
            return 11;
        }else if(x == 'C'){
            return 12;
        }else if(x == 'D'){
            return 13;
        }else if(x == 'E'){
            return 14;
        }else if(x == 'F'){
            return 15;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        try {
            System.out.println(hexToDecimal());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: "i can't use parseInt". check OP statement

Comment: i can't use Integer.parseInt i have to create my own algorithm to convert it

Comment: the code works well but i still cant have Integer.parseInt on your output.add. also the hex i have to convert is very large for example this is one of the hex numbers i have to convert ABCDEFABC